# How to append a file to a bundle in Webpack, or inject required code?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to build a plugin that **injects a module/file into the client bundle.**

An entry config might look like:

```
entry: {
  'main': [
    'some-stuff'
  ],
}
```

And I want to use my plugin like:

```
function SomePlugin(options) {
    this.entryToAppendTo = options.entryToAppendTo
}

...

plugins: [
  new SomePlugin({ entryToAppendTo: 'main' })
]
```

In my plugin I want to require that file as if it were done in Webpack itself, something like:

```
SomePlugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {

    compiler.plugin( 'emit', function( compilation, callback ) {

        var additionalModule = 'my-module?some-stuff=' + Date.now();
        // how to add this to the specified entry?

    })

});
```

Note that I'm passing a dynamic query string, which is why i'm aiming to do this in a plugin.

I want to append a file to the bundle, or somehow inject it into the client bundle. I've tried adding it to `compilation.assets` [as shown here](https://gist.github.com/thatismatt/519d11b2c902791bb74b#file-blah-plugin-js-L26-L33) but it doesn't go into the actual bundle. I've also tried adding a child compiler [as demonstrated in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30344170/743464) but same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to what I was trying to do here (with limited success): [Webpack plugin: how can I modify and re-parse a module after compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092183/webpack-plugin-how-can-i-modify-and-re-parse-a-module-after-compilation)

The problem with just inserting a module into your bundle is that, even if you get it in there, a compiled module in webpack is a function that some other part of the bundled source supposedly calls -- so unless some other part of the bundled source code is `require`ing the bundle you inserted, it won't get executed.

Could you solve this with a custom loader that strategically inserts a `require` for the module you want to include?